# How can we open kendo second pop up after close first popup?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to open kendo pop second pop up after close first popup:

after clicking on kendo first pop1 up close button, I want to open second kendo pop2 up

after click on kendo fist

```
  var pop2= $("#pop2");
  flag_model_popup.kendoWindow({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 582,
                    height:620,
                    title: "",
                    visible: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false


                }).data("kendoWindow").center().close();

         var pop1= $("#pop1");
         flag_model_popup.kendoWindow({
                    modal: true,
                    width: 582,
                    height:620,
                    title: "",
                    visible: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false


                }).data("kendoWindow").center().close();
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: you want this with jquery?

Comment: yes please sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
$("#pop1").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    width: 582,
    height:620,
    title: "",
    visible: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    deactivate: function() {
        var pop2 = $("#pop2").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            width: 582,
            height:620,
            title: "",
            visible: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false
        }).data("kendoWindow").open().center();
    }
}).data("kendoWindow").open().center();
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OGIDE)

The code above creates a second window when the first window's [`deactivate` event](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-deactivate) is called, that is, when the closing animation finishes.

Comment: yeah, this is also fine

Comment: @AjayMalhotra Nice ! Glad to help. If this is your answer, plase check it as an answer tho.